# Issue:Spring Custom Login Returns 403 Access Denied Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting 403 access denied page after entering correct credentials.Here are some of important files.

Spring-Security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

<security:intercept-url pattern="/manageIndustry/viewAddIndustryForm"
    access="hasRole('Recruiter')" />


<security:form-login login-page="/login/"
    default-target-url="/userpage/"
    authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied"
    username-parameter="emailId" 
    password-parameter="userPassword"
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    always-use-default-target="false" />

<security:logout invalidate-session="true" />
<security:csrf />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="LoginService">
 </security:authentication-provider>
```

LoginService.java

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String emailID)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserVO userVO=userDAO.getSingleUserByEmailId(emailID);
    if(userVO==null){
        return null;
    }
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthority=buildSimpleGrantedAuthority(userVO);
    UserDetails userDetails=new User(userVO.getEmailId(),userVO.getUserPassword(),userVO.getIsActive()== 1 ? true : false,true,true,true,grantedAuthority);
    return userDetails;
}

private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> buildSimpleGrantedAuthority(
        final UserVO userVO) {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    if (userVO.getRoleVO() != null) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userVO
                .getRoleVO().getRoleName()));
    }
return grantedAuthorities;
}
```

Login Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/userpage")
public ModelAndView userpage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    log.info(principal);
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = ((UserDetails) principal)
                .getAuthorities();
        if (authorities.size() == 1) {
            final Iterator<? extends GrantedAuthority> iterator = authorities
                    .iterator();
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = iterator.next();
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("Recruiter")) {
                IndustryVO industryVO = new IndustryVO();
                modelAndView.addObject("industryVO", industryVO);
                modelAndView.setViewName("addIndustry");
                return modelAndView;
            }
        }
    }
    modelAndView.setViewName("viewIndustry");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

IndustryController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/manageIndustry")
public class IndustryController {
@Autowired
IndustryDAO industryDAO;

@RequestMapping("/viewAddIndustryForm")
public ModelAndView viewAddIndustryForm() {
    Object principal=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    log.info("this is called");

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    IndustryVO industryVO = new IndustryVO();
    modelAndView.addObject("industryVO", industryVO);
    modelAndView.setViewName("addIndustry");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

After opening `http://localhost:8080/JobPortal/login` and entering correct credentials it redirects me to addIndustry page considering `default-target-url="/userpage/"` and code in Login Controller.

But When I try to access addIndustry page directly without login i.e `http://localhost:8080/JobPortal/manageIndustry/viewAddIndustryForm` it opens login page as per configration  in `Spring-Security.xml` but even after providing correct credentials I am getting `HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of spring security are you using? as far as i remember in old versions you had to add the prefix "ROLE_" to user roles so in your buildSimpleGrantedAuthority you should do something like this:

```
private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> buildSimpleGrantedAuthority(
        final UserVO userVO) {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    if (userVO.getRoleVO() != null) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+userVO
                .getRoleVO().getRoleName()));
    }
return grantedAuthorities;
}
```